# How to configure css or xpath for below code

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

I need to configure xpath or css for selection under red border i.e a name contains "Patient List"

[image]

Comment: May be you want to provide `html` snippet instead of image.

Comment: Flagged the question because it is not test related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you asked for either XPath of CSS but do not forget if you are using selenium webdriver you could also use linkText and partialLinkText.

Here is a Java example of find by "linkText" then click:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Patient List")).click();
```

Or you could also use "partialLinkText" then click:

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Patient List")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be quite simple with xpath:

```
//li[@class='open']//a[text()='Patient List']
```